# Why does this code not work for the second click function? When I am using .not with the css function it works fine?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".click-show").click(function() {
       $(".none").show();``
   });
   $("body").not(".none .click-show").click(function() {
       $(".none").hide();
    });
});
```

I tried with .css function it works fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".click-show").click(function(){
    $(".none").show();
 });
 $("body").not(".none").click(function(){
    $("body").not(".none").css("background-color","blue");

    });
 });
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML also?

Comment: `$("body").not(".none")` selects **only the body element** if it does **not have the** `.none` class. It doesn't select descendant elements etc ?

Answer (score 0):

As per I am getting your question you want to hide a section with class `.none` on body click but excluding on click of elements having class .none and .click-show

Use

$("body").not(".none,.click-show")

instead of

```
$("body").not(".none .click-show")
```